# How to install cordova plugin from a forked repository

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

To install a phonegap plugin I can installed it using

```
cordova plugin install https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP.git
```

and adding the following into config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="com.synconset.cordovahttp" version="0.1.4" />
```

as mentioned in [this official document](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/3379).
Now I need to installed from a [forked repository](https://github.com/brendonparker/cordova-HTTP) and build the app for iOS and because I'm working on Windows, I need to use [Phonegap cloud service](https://build.phonegap.com).

Is it enough to install it using:

```
cordova plugin install https://github.com/brendonparker/cordova-HTTP.git
```

If yes,  what should I put in config.xml?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its as simple as that, all you need is to fork the plugin to your git and then use the cli to add the plugin to your project via

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/username/forked-plugin-name.git`

and then if required edit the config.xml accondingly

Comment: I don't think this still works on Cordova 8 - it will try to fetch this url from NPM where the fork is not published.

Comment: working fine on cordova 10.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Note: by the time this was answered this was the only way of using a fork in phonegap build service. The accepted answer was not an option for phonegap build service, only worked for Cordova users. I won’t update since phonegap build service is now defunct.

Old answer:
You have to publish the fork on npm (with a different id from the original you forked, something like `com-korhani-cordovahttpfork`), and then use it on phonegap build like this:

```
<gap:plugin name="com-korhani-cordovahttpfork" source="npm" />
```

Info about publishing cordova plugins on npm https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html

Comment: not needed, at least not anymore

Comment: The OP was using Phonegap Build service, so my answer was specific for phonegap build service. This is not needed since the service was shut down some time ago. Also not needed if using cordova, but that wasn’t the question asked.